# Split string array evenly into sub arrays whilst using a filter with jq

Tags: arrays, json, select, jq, partition

Given I have the following json

```
[
    "/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/super-admin/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
    "/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/delete-user/tests/index.test.tsx",
    "/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/edit-admin/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
    "/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/delete-admin/tests/index.test.tsx",
    "/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/add-user/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
    "/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/add-admin/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
    "/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/edit-user/tests/index.test.tsx",
    "/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/change-user/tests/index.test.tsx",
    "/home/test-spa/src/other-directory/modals/tests/index.test.ts",
    "/home/test-spa/src/directory/modals/tests/index.test.ts",
]
```

1. I want to exclude anything that has **directory** or **other-directory** in the string
2. I then want to split the array into 4 arrays but I want to evenly split anything that has **integration** in the string i.e I don't want all the integrations in one array. Any other string can then be split across the 4 arrays.

I want to use jq in order to perform this filter. The following code allows me to split the json into 4 but does not do the required filtering as outlined above.

```
jq -cM '[_nwise(length / 4 | floor)]'
```

As a result I am looking for something like the following output (as long as the integration tests are split as evenly as possible, the other strings can then fill in evenly and order does not matter)

```
[
    [
        "/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/super-admin/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
        "/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/delete-user/tests/index.test.tsx"
    ],
    [
        "/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/edit-admin/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
        "/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/delete-admin/tests/index.test.tsx"
    ],
    [
        "/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/add-admin/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
        "/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/edit-user/tests/index.test.tsx"
    ],
    [
        "/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/add-user/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
        "/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/change-user/tests/index.test.tsx"
    ]
]
```

Comment: Where does "4" come from?  Is it a number chosen independently of the data, or is it based on the number of occurrences of "integration" in the relevant strings?

Comment: @peak number is required as ultimately this is aligned with desired number of threads to run on. In my case 4 is the preference but this number could be changed and its not based on the number of occurrences of integration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### If the number of buckets is predetermined

Here's a generic "round-robin" function, written so that the distribution of the "has" and "has not" strings can be performed efficiently (i.e., without concatenating any arrays):

```
# s is a stream, $n a predetermined number of buckets
def roundrobin(s; $n):
   reduce s as $s ({n: 0, a: []}; .a[.n % $n] += [$s] | .n+=1) | .a;
```

```
# First exclude the unwanted elements:
  map(select(test("(other-)?directory")|not))
# Perform the required round-robin:
  | roundrobin( (.[] | select(index("integration"))),
                (.[] | select(index("integration")|not));  4)
```

#### If the number of buckets is data-driven

If the number of buckets should depend on the number of occurrences of the specified string, then using the above-defined `roundrobin` filter, a reasonably efficient solution could be written as follows:

```
# First exclude the unwanted elements:
  map(select(test("(other-)?directory")|not))
# Form an array of the strings with the specified substring
  | map(select(index("integration"))) as $has
# Perform the required round-robin:
  | roundrobin( $has[], ((.-$has)[]); $has|length)
```

Comment: assuming the $has can be changed when dividing the strings to use the preferred number rather than splitting each integration into its own array

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Please see the update.

Comment: @peak - I'm proud to see that your solution is substantially similar to mine, as it shows that I'm finally starting to understand how to do things in jq (the simpler things, at least)! Yours is done with more finesse, though, which is what I've come to expect. One thing I don't understand, though, is how our functions and the use of the functions differ -- does your treating the input as a stream take the place of my building an array of arrays which I then need to flatten before passing through the defined function as a filter?

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is: does `def foo() ...; [x]| flatten | foo` equal `def foo(s) ...; foo(x)`? And does `def foo() ...; x | foo` equal `def foo(f) ...; foo(x)`? Are they both a matter of which looks better, or are there subtle (or not-so-subtle) differences that indicate one usage over the other? Thanks!

(And some day I *will* remember that `map(x)` is the same `[ .[] | x ]`, and looks a lot nicer, too.)

Comment: @JoeCasadonte - Yes, my roundrobin is just the stream-oriented version of your bucket-shift. There’s much to be said here, but in brief it’s often better to start with a stream-oriented def, and then if convenient use it to define an array-oriented version.  As for `flatten` - it has its place of course, but it often limits the applicability of a solution, and as a rule of thumb is best avoided unless the requirements essentially require it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with, to split into N buckets:

```
def bucket_shift($n):
    # loop through all input, shift each elem into bucket 
    reduce .[] as $elem ( { count: 0, rv: [] };
                          (.rv[(.count % $n)] += [$elem] | .count += 1))
                           | .rv ;

# get rid of everything with directory or other-directory
[ .[] | select(test("directory|other-directory") | not) ]

# grab all lines with "integration" in an array
 | [ ([ .[] | select(test("integration")) ]),
# grab all lines without "integration" into a second array
     ([ .[] | select(test("integration") | not) ]) ]
# flatten and divide into buckets (arg passed in)
 | flatten | bucket_shift($num_buckets|tonumber)
```

I labeled each line in your input so that I could track them more easily, then added a couple of extra lines so that the results were not evenly divisible by the number of buckets you wanted, to make sure it would balance well. Lines I and J should be filtered out.

```
<~> $ jq . /tmp/so.json
[
  "A/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/super-admin/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
  "B/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/delete-user/tests/index.test.tsx",
  "C/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/edit-admin/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
  "D/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/delete-admin/tests/index.test.tsx",
  "E/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/add-user/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
  "F/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/add-admin/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
  "G/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/edit-user/tests/index.test.tsx",
  "H/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/change-user/tests/index.test.tsx",
  "IX/home/test-spa/src/other-directory/modals/tests/index.test.ts",
  "JX/home/test-spa/src/directory/modals/tests/index.test.ts",
  "K/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/change-user/tests/index.test.tsx",
  "L/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/add-admin/tests/integration/index.test.tsx"
]
```

The script as above:

```
<~> $ cat /tmp/so.jq
def bucket_shift($n):
    # loop through all input, shift each elem into bucket 
    reduce .[] as $elem ( { count: 0, rv: [] };
                          (.rv[(.count % $n)] += [$elem] | .count += 1))
                           | .rv ;

# get rid of everything with directory or other-directory
[ .[] | select(test("directory|other-directory") | not) ]

# grab all lines with "integration" in an array
 | [ ([ .[] | select(test("integration")) ]),
# grab all lines without "integration" into a second array
     ([ .[] | select(test("integration") | not) ]) ]
# flatten and divide into buckets (arg passed in)
 | flatten | bucket_shift($num_buckets|tonumber)
```

Break out into 4 buckets:

```
<~> $ jq --arg num_buckets 4 -f /tmp/so.jq /tmp/so.json
[
  [
    "A/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/super-admin/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
    "L/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/add-admin/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
    "H/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/change-user/tests/index.test.tsx"
  ],
  [
    "C/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/edit-admin/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
    "B/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/delete-user/tests/index.test.tsx",
    "K/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/change-user/tests/index.test.tsx"
  ],
  [
    "E/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/add-user/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
    "D/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/delete-admin/tests/index.test.tsx"
  ],
  [
    "F/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/add-admin/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
    "G/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/edit-user/tests/index.test.tsx"
  ]
]
```

Break into 3 buckets, instead:

```
<~> $ jq --arg num_buckets 3 -f /tmp/so.jq /tmp/so.json
[
  [
    "A/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/super-admin/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
    "F/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/add-admin/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
    "D/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/delete-admin/tests/index.test.tsx",
    "K/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/change-user/tests/index.test.tsx"
  ],
  [
    "C/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/edit-admin/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
    "L/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/add-admin/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
    "G/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/edit-user/tests/index.test.tsx"
  ],
  [
    "E/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/add-user/tests/integration/index.test.tsx",
    "B/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/delete-user/tests/index.test.tsx",
    "H/home/test-spa/src/components/modals/change-user/tests/index.test.tsx"
  ]
]
```

To have a default bucket size, you can do something like this:

```
bucket_shift($ARGS.named["num_buckets"] // 4|tonumber)
```

Comment: Nice point about default parameter values!